# 段落ごとの単語共起頻度

Tags: r

新聞記事の文章から特定の単語の共起頻度を計算したいのですが、quantedaのfcm()ではどのレベル(一文ごと、段落ごと、文章全体で、など)で頻度を測るか設定することはできますか。

もしくは、その設定がある別のパッケージがあったら教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 0):

私はそのパッケージを使ったことがありませんが, 以下にヘルプが公開されています.
https://quanteda.io/reference/fcm.html
文章全体または, 指定したウィンドウ幅内での共起表現をカウントする関数のようです.
よって文章を文, 段落などお好みのレベルで分割して個別に `fcm()`を適用すればよいかと思います